# FTS3 searches in ORMLite?

Tags: android, ormlite

I know nothing about FTS3, except that http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html says

> performing a full-text search (using FTS3, rather than a LIKE query)
>   can provide a more robust search across text data and can produce
>   results significantly faster

I don't see any mention of FTS3 in the ORMLite documentation, though. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but there is no direct support for this in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).  If the underlying database supports this then you can use ORMLite's raw query interface to process a raw query to the database.  See the documentation here:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries