# How to create virtual table for FTS3 with ORMLite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite, fts3

I  couldn't find a way to use [FTS3](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) with ormlite because, I have problems creating a virtual table.  I need to run something like this in native sqlite:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE enrondata1 USING fts3(content TEXT);
```

But ORMLite calls the below method for creating a simple table

[`TableUtils.createTable(ConnectionSource connectionSource,                             Class<T> dataClass);`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtils.html#createTable%28com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource,%20java.lang.Class%29)

In this answer for the question: [FTS3 searches in ORMLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904558/fts3-searches-in-ormlite), written about using ORMLite's [raw query](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries) interface, unfortunately, I could not find a way to create a table with it.

How can I use FTS3 with ormlite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `queryRaw` function is only for `SELECT` queries. To execute other commands, use [raw execute statements](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#SEC28).

For example:

```
dao.executeRaw("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE enrondata1 USING fts3(content TEXT);");
```